# Hive dynamic partition - "By default Hive won't allow you to create Dynamic partition unless you've atleast one Static partition"

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Reading the article about hive and read the sentences `"By default Hive won't allow you to create Dynamic partition unless you've atleast one Static partition"` . Here what does it mean by "you've atleast one Static partition" . can you please explain?

Comment: unable to find the documentation, do you have the link ?

Comment: If in strict mode `(hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=strict)` Hive won't allow you to create Dynamic partition unless at least one partition column is statically defined.

Comment: Here what does mean " at least one partition column is statically defined". can you please explain with some examples